# How to make entire div clickable with css only

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an entire div be a clickable link, not just the text. I tried various methods like the one outlined [here](http://blog.avtex.com/2012/01/27/how-to-make-an-entire-div-clickable-with-css/) but all that does is make the shapes disappear.

So far I have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/n5xow3cd/2/

```
#productfooter {
width:100%;
max-width:500px;
height: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
 }

#stern {
    background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/t/16/assets/stern-blue-svg.svg?8854319133829452732')
    no-repeat center;
    background-size:100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 165px;
    height: 75px;
    position:absolute;
    display:table;
}

.sterntext {
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
height: 75px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
    padding:0 7px;
}


#stern:hover {
    background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/t/16/assets/stern-blue-filled-svg.svg?18364800561828232638')
no-repeat center;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:100%;

}

#stern a {
    color:#000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12pt;
}

#stern a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

What can I change to make the whole #stern clickable rather than just the text?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, but can you use jQuery? If so, I can answer

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the link and `.sterntext` to 100%? That might work.

Comment: @Jofish I mean I want the entire shape to be clickable, not just the text.

Comment: @JustinLardinois I tried that but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display `.sterntext` as `table-row` and `#stern a` as `table-cell`.

```css
#productfooter {
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#stern {
    background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/t/16/assets/stern-blue-svg.svg?8854319133829452732') no-repeat center;
    background-size:100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 165px;
    height: 75px;
    position:absolute;
    display:table;
}
.sterntext {
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-row;
}
#stern:hover {
    background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/t/16/assets/stern-blue-filled-svg.svg?18364800561828232638') no-repeat center;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:100%;
}
#stern a {
    color:#000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12pt;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
#stern a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="productfooter">
    <div id="stern">
        <p class="sterntext"><a href="#">title title title title title title</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just modify your HTML structure and put `div` inside of the `a` element.

```
<div id="productfooter">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="stern">
             <p class="sterntext">title title title title title title</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5xow3cd/3/

Comment: This is a good way of doing it as well. But I'm working with liquid so making the link use a div instead is a little bit complicated in this particular instance. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Can not edit HTML

```css
/* For functional purposes */

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


/* For design purposes */

div {
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">text here</a></div>
```

We just set the `a` as a `block` and make him take full `width` and full `height`.

## Can edit HTML

```css
/* For functional purposes */

a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}


/* For design purposes */

a {
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">text here</a>
```

We set the `a` as our block.